# Fashion Show ERD

Tags: database-design, erd

working on a class project.

Have to make a ERD for a fashion show.

Not looking for a super in depth ERD, but one that will give a good grade.

I'd like it to be able to

Have a 'Clock-In/Clock-Out system.

Distinguish users.

Director can view everything, and has almost absolute editing power. Manager can view mostly everything, but can edit only their job functions. Assistants can only input data. Any/All users can view their time cards for clock in and out.

Input a data list (to be named total inventory and available inventory), a list of clothing recevied from one Sponsor/Brand. Like 3, Red, Gucci, Sleeveless, Dress. Or 4, Blue, Gucci, High-Heels.

Be able to create outfits, aka combinations of clothing from inventory. Then update the inventory after an outfit is created. If 1, 'Red Dress' and 1, 'Blue High-Heels' are used for an outfit. The available inventory should reflect this.

Dunno if this is too much already but I'd like there to be a checklist of sorts for the director to use when evaluating a venue. Only the director would have access to this.

I have made a sample ERD based on what I think it should look like. Please give me whatever feedback you can, thank you so much!

ERD:

[image: ERD Fashion Show]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site!  "Can you give me feedback..." questions are generally viewed as [off-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and usually get closed as "opinion based". If you have *specific* questions/concerns/problems about your database design, ask those questions instead.

Comment: I'll also add that getting help on school assignments is definitely allowed, though most answerers will generally avoid providing "too much" help on school assignments, preferring to help you get past specific blockers, rather than trying to simply correct/improve your homework before the teacher sees it. We care about helping you solve problems & learn--but aren't so concerned about what grades you make.

Comment: Think of the questions this ERD must answer. Can you navigate it to answer those queries? If "yes" for everything then you're done. This will mean limiting the scope to specific use-cases, which is a very proper concern in professional software development.